Stepping back from being a moderator
I've let my diamond lapse. I achieved a lot as a mod and got some interesting insights. The site is slow these days and the overall vibe is ok I reckon.
If black & white gets painted in rainbows or a cow flatulates in the neigbours field and everyone goes on strike, I'll get myself re-elected.

Thanks for doing all that work! Won't you lose access to the company Yacht(s) when you quit? :)

@nvoigt I'm Polynesian, I got my own canoe and my swimming pool is the Pacific Ocean ;)

[I think  stepping down is the usual way to express resignation.] You were a good no-nonsense moderator.

@Mari-LouA Thanks, but I just let it lapse organically when the opportunity arose. Our site is healthy in mod terms imo. There's a good team of mods.

Sorry to see you go Kilisi! You've been an exceedingly important contributor to the mod team!
Personally I'd like to add that I've found the perspective you've brought invaluable both in enriching the community as well as challenging me to rethink things in my personal and professional life.

Thanks, I appreciate it. I'm not leaving the site, it's been a great experience and a valuable personal learning asset for the same reasons, for almost 9 years!

@Kilisi Ah, didn't phrase that right, I realised it was just the mod team you're stepping back from. On towards that 10-year milestone then. ;)
